# weird chars at the end of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, smart-pointers

what i want to do is to read the chars from a buffer array

```
std::vector<char> SmartIO::PeekChar(){
        int newlen= 0;
        while(buffer[ptrSeek] != 0){
            ptrSeek++;
            newlen++;
        }

        std::vector<char> temp(newlen);
        memcpy(temp.data(),&buffer[ptrSeek-newlen],newlen);
        ptrSeek = 0;
        return temp;
}
```

so `temp.data()` returns for an e.g `methodtest‎‎‎‎««««««««î‏` while the result should be `methodtest` only!
so what is causing this weird chars?

Comment: Obviously, there's no `\0` byte after "methodtest".

Comment: unrelated : dont use `shared_ptr<char>` to point to a new'd array of `char` it will do the wrong thing on destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer / character array is not null-terminated.

You must know the length of the buffer or it have to be null terminated.

Comment: what about now it still the same issue

Comment: no, what you did makes your "ptrSeek" zero. It didn't change the string, just the index. You need to do: " buffer[ptrSeek] = 0; " to actually change the string.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

You can't use shared_ptr like that as it will call the wrong delete. It needs to call delete[].

You can adjust that by using a custom deleter or `boost::shared_array<char>`

Aside from that, to print from a character array it needs a null terminator. You will need to allocate a byte for that too, and you can use strcpy.

I would only use shared_array if you want to copy it around a few times and avoid re-allocations, otherwise I would just use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` (the former if you want a writable array of characters).

Comment: :- if used vector and i tired to say .data() it will give me the same result with ««««««««î

Comment: if you allocate the space for the null terminator with vector<char> by sizing it (not reserve) it will automatically put the 0 in there for you. vector doesn't have a member function called data() by the way, you use &v[0] to read it as a (const) char*